# Angular 5 - Horizontal scrolling using buttons

Tags: angular

I have implemented horizontal scrolling of cards in an angular application. The scrolling is working fine. However, I would like to the give the user also the ability to scroll left or right, by clicking the "Left" and "Right" buttons. Each button should only scroll it's own `msgCardDeck`.

Here's my code on StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atnq4z

Here's my typescript to make it scroll, but it's not working. Would appreciate if there's a way to do this.

```
// Scroll Left if there is anything to scroll
  scrollLeft() {
    document.querySelector('div.msgCard').scrollLeft -= 500;
  }

// Scroll Right if there is any area to scroll

  scrollRight() {
    document.querySelector('div.msgCard').scrollLeft += 500;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

pass event object as argument to the function.

```
// necessary changes for ts.
 scrollLeft(e) {
    let wrapper = e.srcElement.closest('.msgCardScrollWrapper');
    wrapper.querySelector('.msgCardDeck').scrollLeft -= 500;
 }

 scrollRight(e) {
    let wrapper = e.srcElement.closest('.msgCardScrollWrapper');
    wrapper.querySelector('.msgCardDeck').scrollLeft += 500;
 }
 // necessary changes for html.
 <div class="msgCardNavRightButton" (click) = "scrollRight($event)">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
  </div>

 <div class="msgCardNavLeftButton" (click) = "scrollLeft($event)">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's pretty close. Posted the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following enhancement from Hardik's answer worked for me:

```
// necessary changes for ts.
     scrollLeft(e) {
        // find parent element; which has scrollable div.
        let wrapper = e.srcElement.closest('.msgCardScrollWrapper');
        let totalWidth = wrapper.querySelector('.msgCardDeck').clientWidth;
        // apply value to scrollable div.
        wrapper.querySelector('.msgCardDeck').scrollLeft -= totalWidth/2;
     }

     scrollRight(e) {
        let wrapper = e.srcElement.closest('.msgCardScrollWrapper');
        // find parent element; which has scrollable div.
        let totalWidth = wrapper.querySelector('.msgCardDeck').clientWidth;
        // apply value to scrollable div.
        wrapper.querySelector('.msgCardDeck').scrollLeft += totalWidth/2;
     }

     // necessary changes for html.
     <div class="msgCardNavRightButton" (click)="scrollRight($event)">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
      </div>

     <div class="msgCardNavLeftButton" (click)="scrollLeft($event)">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
     </div>
```